# How to call trigger after creating or deleting every Table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use SQL Server, I need to call a `Triger` after creating or deleting every Table.

I want to execute a code after creating or deleting a table

I have a table `TableShemaChanges` where I want to keep the table changes.

How can I do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The question is to broad for a detailed answer but you may start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stated [here](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/sql-server-ddl-trigger/)

> SQL Server **DDL** triggers respond to server or database events
>   rather than to table data modifications. These events created by the
>   Transact-SQL statement that normally starts with one of the following
>   keywords `CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DROP`, `GRANT`, `DENY`, `REVOKE`, or
>   `UPDATE STATISTICS`.
>
> For example, you can write a DDL trigger to log whenever a user issues
>   a CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statement.
>
> The DDL triggers are useful in the following cases:
>
> - Record changes in the database schema.
> - Prevent some specific changes to the database schema.
> - Respond to a change in the database schema.
>
> The following shows the syntax of creating a DDL trigger:
>
> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
> ON { DATABASE |  ALL SERVER}
> [WITH ddl_trigger_option]
> FOR {event_type | event_group }
> AS {sql_statement}
> ```

**Sample Query**

```
CREATE TRIGGER safety   
ON DATABASE   
FOR DROP_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE   
AS   
   PRINT 'You must disable Trigger "safety" to drop or alter tables!'   
   ROLLBACK;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set trigger for INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE events on table.

Comment: The OP is looking for DDL triggers. What you are describing are DML triggers.